# How to calculate the area of raster catchment zones?

Tags: qgis

I have a raster with irregular shape and I need to calculate the area. The "classic" method (Vectorize+field calculator) didn't work, it makes thousands of polygons. Any ideas?

[image: Raster image]

Comment: What about the "(total_pixels - nodata_pixels) * pixel_area" method?

Comment: Alternative is to reclassify your DEM before vectorization. For instance with the QGIS raster calculator you could extract all cells different than the no-data value and then vectorize the resulting raster shape. This will give you a single polygon...

Comment: @Vince Please consider posting this as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just trying to capture the area in map units (it's not in a geographic coordinate system), then it isn't necessary to take the time to do an expensive vector conversion.

I'm not a QGISer, but I expect there's a simple way to describe the raster to capture pixel height, pixel width, number of rows, number of columns, and number of NODATA pixels.  From there, you just need a simple math expression:

```
area = ((nRows * nCols) - numNODATA) * pixH * pixW
```